# Django custom context_processors in render_to_string method

Tags: python, django

I'm building a function to send email and I need to use a context_processor variable inside the HTML template of the email, but this don't work.

Example:

```
def send_email(plain_body_template_name, html_body_template_name):
    plain_body = loader.render_to_string(plain_body_template_name, context)
    html_body = loader.render_to_string(html_body_template_name, context)
    email_msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(body=plain_body)
    email_msg.attach_alternative(html_body, 'text/html')
    email_message.send()
```

In my custom `context_processor.py` I just have a function that receive a `HttpRequest` and return a dict like `{'foo': 'bar'}`, and in the template I try to render using `{{foo}}`.

I added the context_processor in the `TEMPLATE['OPTIONS']['context_processors']` too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `django` backend in your `TEMPLATE` with

`'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',`

django is seeing that you haven't passed in a request and opting for a basic `Context` to wrap your dict instead of a `RequestContext` which will handle the `context_processors` you've defined.

You can probably get away with doing

`html_body = loader.render_to_string(html_body_template_name, context, request=request)`

but you'd need to pass in the request object.

This might not make sense though. Are you emailing the person making the request? Does the context make sense to include?

If your context processor doesn't need the `request` then I'd either make it a simple utility function (if it's only called here) or make the request parameter optional, import it into this module, and add it directly into the context

`context = {"my_var": 1}
context.update(your_extra_context())
loader.render_to_string(...)`

There are some complicated ways of updating a `Context()` in layers, but I don't think that's necessary here.

Comment: Thanks @user3208419, in this specific case I don't need the request. I followed your solution to update `context` param with my custom `context_processors` and keep it in the `template['OPTIONS']['context_processors']` to another templates with `request` param.

Comment: This is a trick/hack to update context  from context processors or settings to context.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem - I needed to render template to string with context processor values, but at the same time request object was None (running command from console). Then I found this approach:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if not request:
        context = {'param1':'value1'}
        return render_to_string('myapp/index.html', RequestContext(None, context))
    else:
        #render as usual
        render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
        pass
```

when you pass [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) instead of dictionary, it populates values of all context processors into the context. But request must be optional in all your context processors, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: This gives me the error `context must be a dict rather than RequestContext.`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me but instead of returnin 'render_to_string', I returned a HttpResponse with the result of 'render_to_string' as an argument, and instead of "RequestContext", just a plain dictionary.

Comment: RequestContext Deprecated since version 1.8