# Django: Display website name in Template/Emails without using Sites framework

Tags: python, django

I want to render my website name in django templates. [Django's own docs on Sites state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/):

> Use it **if** your single Django installation **powers more than one** site
>   and you need to differentiate between those sites in some way.

My django app doesn't. I know I can *still* use it, but it seems like an overkill. I just want to pull a variable with my website's name (!= domain) in ANY template. I don't want to pass it in views either because that doesn't seem DRY enough.

Writing a custom processor seemed like a simple-enough option, but for some reason these variables aren't available in the .txt emails django-registration sends (while other variables definitely are, so I guess it's not impossible).

TIA

Edit: was asked to include code that doesn't work:

processors.py:

```
def get_website_name(request):
    website_name = 'SomeWebsite'
    return {'mysite_name': website_name}
```

Included successfully in `context_processors` in settings.py. It works nicely in "regular" templates, but not in emails.

Here's how I'm sending the emails, inside a `change_email_view`:

```
msg_plain = render_to_string('email_change_email.txt', context)
            msg_html = render_to_string('email_change_email.html', context)

            send_mail(
                'Email change request',
                msg_plain,
                'my@email',
                [profile.pending_email],
                html_message=msg_html,
            )
```

A **further** problem is that django-regitration further abstracts some of those views away: so when a user registers, wants to reset a password, etc...I don't even have access to the views.

Comment: Well, since you changed the question a little - it would be helpful to see the code that does not work regarding your context processor. For jinja2 environments  are recommended instead of context processors - see the linked docs in the anwser.

Comment: @dahrens: added. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: And how do you render email templates? Can you add this code, too?

Comment: based on the comment under my answer: is it possibile that `render_to_string` does not use jinja2 but django template engine? May you also show us how you render your common views with jinja2 if you do not use the template backend?

Comment: Regarding render_to_string: I'm not sure if you're hinting, mocking, or asking. Regarding my "common" views: I pass variables  a dictionary to `render(request...` in the view, and access a variable like so: `{{ var_name}}`.

Comment: By default django uses its own template engine - how do you tell your django to use jinja2 instead - the common way would be the template backend but you told that you are not using it?

Comment: I'm using `django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates` as the backend. I see I might have misled you now with the first sentence.

Comment: I adjusted this in your question :)

Comment: @dahrens actually up until now I thought they were the same/interchangeable. At this point I'm simply considering doing all the variable-passing manually since the effort doesn't seem worth it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Django custom context_processors in render_to_string method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339569/django-custom-context-processors-in-render-to-string-method#39340015) you should pass the request to `render_to_string`.

```
msg_plain = render_to_string('email_change_email.txt', context, request=request)
msg_html = render_to_string('email_change_email.html', context, request=request)
```

Comment: error: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'environment'`

Comment: As I understand, this involves more than just adding the lines you added in this answer. I've already gone ahead and done that. (You have to specify a different backend, not only set an environment). It didn't work anyway even after I followed some SO answers on the subject.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer a little - you do configure django to use jinja2 as described above? Which version of django do you use?

Comment: I'm on Django 1.11. I cannot make the switch to `jinja2` backend now I'm afraid, too many configurations that will clash. I've already tried and it starting errors right and left. I also tried prepedning/appending jinja to the TEMPLATES list variable, and it didn't work either.

Comment: I just attempted again given your suggestions. And If I append this to my setting, it doesn't even work in the views.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on the new information. Please let me know if this works now.

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks **very** much for your patience. Do you know how can I pass request when using django-registration? I don't really have access to the views that generate the emails...I think it plugs to some django base-view or something.

Comment: You always have access to all views that you use - if you wrote them yourself or if you use them from an app. File another question as this is not really related to this question.

Comment: just did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062985/passing-context-to-django-registrations-views