# Passing context to django-registration's views

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm utilizing [django-registration](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/index.html) with a set of premade templates I found on Github for doing a two-step (registration-activation) workflow [using HMAC](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/hmac.html).

I want to pass global variables (defined in context-processors) like my website's name to the emails sent by django-registration. the activation email sent to a new registrant, for example, or the password change one.

The "problem" is I don't directly have access to those views. That's kinda the point of django-registration, you include its path in the `urls.py` file, and everything works:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('core.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
]
```

What's the minimum effort way of adding context to those views? I've already created and am successfully [passing context to emails in my own views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053428/django-display-website-name-in-template-emails-without-using-sites-framework) (using context processors):

```
def send_some_email_view(request):

    msg_plain = render_to_string('email_change_email.txt', context, request=request)
   msg_html = render_to_string('email_change_email.html', context, request=request)
```

But what about views I didn't create?

Edit: So I made some progress, finding django-registration's registration view, and this method inside of it:

```
def send_activation_email(self, user):
    """
    Send the activation email. The activation key is simply the
    username, signed using TimestampSigner.

    """
    activation_key = self.get_activation_key(user)
    context = self.get_email_context(activation_key)
    context.update({
        'user': user
    })
    subject = render_to_string(self.email_subject_template,
                               context)
    # Force subject to a single line to avoid header-injection
    # issues.
    subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
    message = render_to_string(self.email_body_template,
                               context)
    user.email_user(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
```

I don't want to override it inside the source code because that would prevent me from updating. So now the question becomes: Is my only way out writing a view that subclasses this view, and overriding the method? This means I'm writing separate views for every view provided by django-registartion that needs to send an email...

Comment: Oh -  I read the last passage after writing the answer - shame on me. This is usually the drawback when using 3rd party libraries. You might use the site feature as this is intended - or write a patch for django-registration that allows you set additional context data for emails through settings - maybe they like it.

Comment: Oh well, or you just provide a patch that also passes the request to `render_to_string` for all their email template rendering calls - this would be just a few changed lines and I guess they will appreciate this as it should not have any side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, Thanks to the direction dahrens' answer sent me to:

```
# myapp/processors.py
def get_website_name(request):
    website_name = 'ExcitingWebsiteThatsComingSoon'
    return {'mysite_name': website_name}

# some views.py file
from myapp.processors import get_website_name

class RegistrationViewWithContext(RegistrationView):
    def get_email_context(self, user):
        context = super().get_email_context(user)
        context['req'] = get_website_name(self.request)
        return context
```

Basically, I'm simply using my custom processor to inject the website's name. It isn't as clean as I hoped it would be: While in my templates I can simply use `{{ mysite_name}}`, in the email template I have to use `{{req.mysite_name}}`. But this does have the DRY-ness I aimed for: all templates updating accordingly if the variable in the function changes.

I'll mark my answer as correct for now and will update accordingly if any new answers come in.

Answer (score 2):

First create your own view based on the vendor view and overwrite your desired  method:

```
from registration.backends.hmac.views import RegistrationView


class CustomRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_email_context(self, user):
        context = super().get_email_context(user)
        return RequestContext(self.request, context)
```

Than have a look at `registration.backends.hmac.urls.py` ([source](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/master/registration/backends/hmac/urls.py)). They just define a bunch of urls there.

You can easily overwrite just one of them by adding your own **before** you include the one from the app.

```
from yourapp import views


urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.CustomRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
    # [...]
]
```

While changing just the necessary things you also get some insight of whats going on in your 3rd party app, which is always an advantage. This applies to most 3rd party apps not just the one you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The issue is, I want to be as DRY as possible so I'm again trying to utilize the global variable I've set in request in my custom context processor. However, when I do `context['mysite_name'] = RequestContext(self.request).get('mysite_name')`, it returns None. `mysite_name` is used successfully in templates so I'm kind of at odds on why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you provide more information about where you make this assignment? Btw.: I've added some information on the github issue, which I guess you opened.

Comment: I'm making it in a view subclassing dj's `RegistrationView` which I am now using. It looks identical to the one in your answer, except for the line in my comment above. It appears though, that `self.request` doesn't contain the variable at this stage in the workflow...? or it's a different kind of request?

Comment: so I managed to do it by doing the assignment as follows: `context['req'] = get_website_name(self.request)` where `get_website_name` is function inside my `processors.py` file, I then access `{{req.mysite_name}}` in the email template. It isn't ideal as it's not the *exact same*  same reference across templates, but it does mean changing the variable in the function will update all references accordingly. Oh well.

Comment: I slightly adjusted the above based on your feedback, may you give it a try? The content of the request should have nothing to do with it. Using a RequestContext should only ensure that the context processors get triggered.

Comment: That ended up with an error `context must be a dict rather than RequestContext`. I added my own solution, which is largely based on yours. Thanks once again!